no basic auth credentials when SSH'd in as ec2-user
I'm setting up a GitHub Action which provisions a remote server for my application's needs.  It's a unique setup, I know there are other tools that are better suited for the job, but this approach will work well for us.
Assume in other steps that Docker, Docker Compose and AWS CLI have already been installed using the SSH approach used here and I've confirmed are functional.  Running the below step, I'm seeing a no basic auth credentials error when trying to pull the image
  - name: Install AWS Credential Helper
    run: |
      SSH_COMMAND_OUTPUT=$(ssh ec2-user@${{ secrets.AWS_INSTANCE_IP }} <<EOF
        if ! command -v docker-credential-ecr-login &> /dev/null; then
          curl -Lo /tmp/docker-credential-ecr-login https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper/releases/latest/download/docker-credential-ecr-login-linux-amd64
          chmod +x /tmp/docker-credential-ecr-login
          sudo mv /tmp/docker-credential-ecr-login /usr/local/bin/
        fi

        aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${{ secrets.DOCKER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${{ secrets.DOCKER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

        # I've confirmed contains the key/secret specified
        cat ~/.aws/credentials
        echo "{
          \"credsStore\": \"ecr-login\"
        }" > ~/.docker/config.json
      
        # Unsure if this is needed... 
        sudo systemctl restart docker
           
        # Shows the correct path of /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login
        which docker-credential-ecr-login

        # I can confirm this containers the credsStore setting
        cat ~/.docker/config.json

        # This file doesn't exist, according to some of what I've seen, it could contain log entries on an auth failure
        cat ~/.ecr/log/ecr-login.log

        docker pull xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/cli:commit-f1c73c88
      EOF
      )

Notice here I'm SSHing as ec2-user, but using sudo to restart docker.  I wondered whether that would cause an issue, so I also tried setting things via root and encountered failures:
            sudo aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${{ secrets.DOCKER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
            sudo aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${{ secrets.DOCKER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          
            sudo echo "{
              \"credsStore\": \"ecr-login\"
            }" > /etc/docker/config.json

This resulted in bash: line 14: /etc/docker/config.json: Permission denied which of course ended up with a fail to pull the image.
What steps can I take to troubleshooting the auth failure?
